# How to get a substring from the beginning till the middle of a word using regex

Tags: java, regex

Java :
If the given string is `"\\path\test\files\loading\hold\sample.text"`. The start of the string should be `\\path` followed by any text till `\loading`. I need a pattern that matches in the string.

if the pattern matches need to replace with ..

Input : `"\\path\test\files\loading\hold\sample.text"`.
expected output as `"..\hold\sample.text"`

Comment: You say you want to match till ``\loading``, but you expect to get a string with a comma before `text`, why? What is your current code?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I am assuming `path` is a real word. This also includes the `\` after loading so it would not change paths where `loading` would be `loadingPlatform` or `somewordloading` which may produce undesirable results. Note that the back slashes need to be escape once for the String and once for the regex engine.

```
String s = "\\path\\test\\files\\loading\\hold\\sample.text";
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\path.*\\\\loading\\\\", "..\\\\");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
..\hold\sample.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the regex, `\\\\path.*\\loading` with `..` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\\\\path\\test\\files\\loading\\hold\\sample.text";
        System.out.println(str);

        str = str.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\path.*\\\\loading", "..");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
\\path\test\files\loading\hold\sample.text
..\hold\sample.text
```

Note that `\` is a meta-character and therefore you need an extra `\` for each `\` in order to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String input = "\\path\\test\\files\\loading\\hold\\sample.text";
        String output=input.replaceFirst(".*\\\\loading","..");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all answer<sup>**1**</sup> so far are missing the "The **start of the string** should be `\\path`" condition - recommend using an `^` to force it to be the start of the string (if that is really a condition):
`replaceFirst("^\\\\...`

(I also prefer using `replaceFirst` in this case, since only interested in replacing the first match, otherwise I would use `replaceAll`, but then `^` would be wrong)

Note that all given answer so far are looking for the last occurrence of `loading`, in case there are more than one (probably the wanted behavior)

Also note that backslash is not only an escape character for regular expression, but also one for Java literals, so literal for the regular expression needs 4 backslashes to match a single backslash, see official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs).

<sup>**1** I will not reproduce the other answers here, not risking being accused of plagiarism</sup>